# Swift HTTP request works on the simulator but not in a real device

Tags: json, ios-simulator, httprequest, watchos-2

i created a watchOS app that request a value from an API and show it on a label.
It is working perfectly in the simulator but when I execute it on my Apple Watch it crashes with the following error:

```
[ERROR] There is an unspecified error with the connection
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The first error is generated by my code.

The code I wrote is:

```
func price_request() -> NSData? {

    guard let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.xxxxx.com/xxx.php") else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
        print("[ERROR] There is an unspecified error with the connection")
        return nil
    }

    print("[CONNECTION] OK, data correctly downloaded")
    return data
}

func json_parseData(data: NSData) -> NSDictionary? {
    do {
        let json: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        print("[JSON] OK!")

        return (json as? NSDictionary)

    } catch _ {
        print("[ERROR] An error has happened with parsing of json data")
        return nil
    }
}
```

I tried also to add the App Transport Security bypass also if it is not needed because of a request to an HTTPS URL but it does not works.

Can you please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using NSURLSession to get data...

```
//declare data task
var task: URLSessionDataTask?

//setup the session
let url = URL(string:"https://url.here")!
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

 task = session.dataTask(with: url){ (data, res, error) -> Void in
        if let e = error {
            print("dataTaskWithURL fail: \(e.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        if let d = data {
           //do something
        }
    }
    task!.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it in a few hours

Comment: I send some fix to your code, like changing NSUrl to URL instead.